# Display a child URL with a parent URL in the back history of WKWebView in iOS

Tags: ios, webview, wkwebview

I want to display a new `WKWebView` instance, such that the page currently displayed to user is the **childURL**, but another URL, **parentURL**, is in the back history of the WKWebview, such that if the user goes back in history (through a gesture or through a button which calls `WKWebView`'s **goBack** function) then **parentURL** will be displayed.

Imagine loading **parentURL** at first in the webview, then tapping a link that goes to **childURL**. I want this (**childURL** is displayed, **parentURL** in the back history) to be my initial state in the `WKWebView`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried to modify the history with javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest：

1. A `WKWebView` displays your `childURL` in the beginning.
2. When tapping the go back button, the `WKWebView` make a new request of the `parentURL`. The button should be a native iOS UIButton. After tapped the go-back-button, change its action to make the `WKWebView` not to request the `parentURL` again.
3. If the go-back-button is in the .html, try to interact with javascript.
4. If there is some other problems left, talk to me.

If your urls is different `.html`s, I think it is simple to do what i say. Your `go back` is just go to a new url actually.

Comment: How about if user went back using the pan gesture? Can you intercept that?

Comment: @DjS 1. load the parentURL first. in the `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)` load childURL. 2. After both childURL and parentURL are loaded. Add the wkwebview to your screen.